# About data mining by using twitter data

Tags: twitter, text-mining

I plan to write a thesis about using sentiment information to enhance the predictivity of some financial trading model for currency.

The sentiment data should be twitter threads including some keyword, like "EUR.USD". And I will filter out some sentiment words to identify the sentiment. Simple idea. Then we try to see whether here is any relation between the degree of sentiment and the movement of EUR.USD.

My big concern is on twitter data. As we all know that the twitter set up the limit to see the history data. You could only browser back for like 5 days. It is not enough since our strategy based on daily sentiment.

I noticed that google have some fantastic thing like timeline about the twitter updates: http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/googles_twitter_timeline_lets_you_explore_the_past.php

But first of all, I am in Switzerland and seems I have no such function on my google which is too smart to identify my location and may block some US google version function like this. Secondly, even I could see some fancy interactive google timeline control on my firefox, How could I dig out data from my query and save them? Does google supply such api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google service you mentioned has shut down recently so you won't be able to use it. (http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-realtime-shuts-down-as-twitter-deal-expires/31007/)

If you need a longer timespan of data to analyze I see the following options:

- pay for historical data :) (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-data-providers)
- if you don't want to pay, you need to fetch tweets containing EUR/USD whatever else (you could use the streaming API for this) and store them somehow. Run this service for a while (if possible) and you'll have more than just 5 days of data.

Comment: Dear Norbip, Thank you very much for your answer with multiple strategies on my project. It is really helpful, although it is sad that google shut down the service....You can never rely on No-evil big company, right?:) I will try to figure out by myself and see what is possible. I guess the second way is best and I need to collect the data by myself from today:)

Comment: Actually I was wrong about the Streaming API. Streaming API returns a superset of results compared to search API, and sampling is an optional thing. I've edited my answer according to this. I suggest to go with the Streaming API. ;)